# Install and use specific NPM dependency globally

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I use an npm package which has a dependancy which requires chromium.  My build pipeline and release process means that this is being downloaded for every release, and can take up to 30s to download each time.

Is there any way chromium, or this dependancy, can be installed globally so it doesn't need to be installed on every release?

Note: I'd rather not share the node_modules directory between releases

Comment: You mean like `npm install --global`?

Comment: @goto1 I guess, but only for a specific dependancy, and only if that will then use that instead of installing a local version

Comment: Right, so `npm instal --global chromium`?

Comment: well, that would install it globally, but it would still be installed locally right?

Comment: No, this would only install it globally. If you're asking whether you're going to be able to use it in a similar way as if it was installed locally then the answer is yes.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking, I'm asking if there's any way I can install this so the package I'm installing, which has it as a dependancy, will use the globally installed version, to save having to install it on every release

Comment: Then you should be installing globally the package that you need rather than installing a dependency of it.

Comment: I understand I can do that but I did not want the entire package installed globally, just this dependancy, which is why I asked the question in the first place

Comment: Right, what you're asking cannot be done.